# What is the difference between => and : in an Elixir map?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In the Phoenix framework

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  json conn, Repo.get(User, id)
end
```

matches fine, but using the `:` notation does not pattern match

```
def show(conn, %{"id": id}) do
  json conn, Repo.get(User, id)
end
```

when I call the following code from a test

```
conn
|> get(user_path(conn, :show, user.id))
|> json_response(200)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**`%{key: value}` is a short-hand for `Atom` keys, not `String` keys.** Let's clear up a few things:

```ex
:"a" == "a"
# => false

:"a" == :a
# => true

%{:a => 1} == %{"a": 1}
# => true
```

So when you write `%{"id": id}`, it means: `%{id: id}` which is **not** `%{"id" => id}`, and since your params map does not have an `:id` key, it does not match.

---

<sup>*As a side note, I actually wrote a [Plug](https://github.com/sheharyarn/better_params) to use atom keys in Phoenix controllers to keep params matching short and sweet.*</sup>

Answer (score 3):

When you use `:` the key is an atom. When you use `=>` the key is whatever the type actually is. `%{key: val}` is actually just sugar for `%{:key => val}`.